# Review time is not returned in response

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am using Google Places API to get Place details with reviews. Previously I was getting each review's time in the response.

For example,

```
"reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "Robert Ardill",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106422854611155436041/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T47KxWuAoJU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZo/BDmyI12BZAs/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba1/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
            "text" : "Awesome offices. Great facilities, location and views. Staff are great hosts",
            "time" : 1491144016
         }
      ]
```

But it looks like, after the new new billing changes in google APIs, the time value is not returned in the response.
Now i m getting a response like the following one

```
"reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "Robert Ardill",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106422854611155436041/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-T47KxWuAoJU/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAZo/BDmyI12BZAs/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba1/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "a month ago",
            "text" : "Awesome offices. Great facilities, location and views. Staff are great hosts"
         }
      ]
```

This is the line of code i am using to make the API call
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=MY_API_KEY&placeid=MY_PLACE_ID&fields=review

If I remove the fields parameter in the web service call like below, the time value is returned in response with each review data properly. 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=MY_API_KEY&placeid=MY_PLACE_ID

This looks like a bug in Google API side. I have subitted a bug in Google issuetracker.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113753944?pli=1

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for your issue? I checked on the bug tracker, seems there were responses; I have a not so common solution but I'm curious if you were able to get the results you needed

Comment: @Ilan P No..I have not yet found a solution. Google team is working on this bug  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112831939

Comment: I wrote a custom API which pulls using the feature_id (FID) I use at reviewsmaker.com which is a service for GMB users; if you need access I can arrange for you, I was curious if you did get it resolved as the time stamp field is a pretty important attribute; I wasn’t even aware Google removed it from the places API results

Comment: Thanks @IIan P. For time being till google resolves the issue(https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112831939), i removed the fields parameter from the api call and thus all premium data will be fetched . I also have reduced the api polling frequency to reduce the billing to some extent.